# How to check user choice algorithm

Tags: algorithm, testing, heuristics

I have an algorithm that chooses a list of items that should fit the user's likings.
I'll skip the algorithm's details because of confidentiality issues...

Now, I'm trying to think of a way to check it statistically, with a group of people.
The way I'm checking it now is:

1. Algorithm gets best results per user.
2. shuffle top 5 results with lowest 5 results.
3. make person list the results he liked by order (0 = liked best, 9 = didn't like)
4. compare user results to algorithm results.

I'm doing this because i figured that to show that algorithm chooses good results, i need to put in some bad results and show that the algorithm knows its a bad result as well.

So, what I'm asking is:

Is shuffling top results with low results is a good idea ?

And if not, do you have an idea on how to get good statistics on how good an algorithm  matches user preferences (we have users that can choose stuff) ?

Comment: This is a general problem with heuristic algorithms.

Comment: ok, added heuristics to the tags

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First ask yourself:

> **What am I trying to measure?**

Not to rag on the other submissions here, but while mjv and Sjoerd's answers offer some plausible heuristic reasons for why what you are trying to do may not work as you expect; they are not constructive in the sense that they do not explain why your experiment is flawed, and what you can do to improve it.  Before either of these issues can be addressed, what you need to do is define what you hope to measure, and only then should you go about trying to devise an experiment.

Now, I can't say for certain what would constitute a good metric for your purposes, but I can offer you some suggestions.  As a starting point, you could try using a precision vs. recall graph:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall

This is a standard technique for assessing the performance of ranking and classification algorithms in machine learning and information retrieval (ie web searching).  If you have an engineering background, it could be helpful to understand that precision/recall generalizes the notion of precision/accuracy:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accuracy_and_precision

Now let us suppose that your algorithm does something like this; it takes as input some prior data about a user then returns a ranked list of other items that user might like.  For example, your algorithm is a web search engine and the items are pages; or you have a movie recommender and the items are books.  This sounds pretty close to what you are trying to do now, so let us continue with this analogy.

Then the precision of your algorithm's results on the first n is the number of items that the user actually liked out of your first to top n recommendations:

```
    precision = #(items user actually liked out of top n) / n
```

And the recall is the number of items that you actually got right out of the total number of items:

```
    recall = #(items correctly marked as liked) / #(items user actually likes)
```

Ideally, one would want to maximize both of these quantities, but they are in a certain sense competing objectives.  To illustrate this, consider a few extremal situations:  For example, you could have a recommender that returns everything, which would have perfect recall, but very low precision.  A second possibility is to have a recommender that returns nothing or only one sure-fire hit, which would have (in a limiting sense) perfect precision, but almost no recall.

As a result, to understand the performance of a ranking algorithm, people typically look at its precision vs. recall graph.  These are just plots of the precision vs the recall as the number of items returned are varied:

[image]

Image taken from the following tutorial (which is worth reading): 
http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/evaluation-of-ranked-retrieval-results-1.html

Now to approximate a precision vs recall for your algorithm, here is what you can do.  First, return a large set of say n, results as ranked by your algorithm.  Next, get the user to mark which items they actually liked out of those n results.  This trivially gives us enough information to compute the precision at every partial set of documents < n (since we know the number).   We can also compute the recall (as restricted to this set of documents) by taking the total number of items liked by the user in the entire set.  This, we can plot a precision recall curve for this data.  Now there are fancier statistical techniques for estimating this using less work, but I have already written enough.  For more information please check out the links in the body of my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Your method is biased. If you use the top 5 and bottom 5 results, It is very likely that the user orders it according to your algorithm. Let's say we have an algorithm which rates music, and I present the top 1 and bottom 1 to the user:

- [Queen](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Queen_%28band%29)
- [The Cheeky Girls](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/The_Cheeky_Girls)

Of course the user will mark it exactly like your algorithm, because the difference between the top and bottom is so big. You need to make the user rate randomly selected items.

Comment: It's not an absolute rating. it rates according to user. But how can i show the fact that the algorithm chose the right items ? i need to put the algorithm's top items there, (so the user rates the top items relatively to something), but what else ?

Comment: I figured that putting the lowest result in there, and the user chooses accordingly, will show that algorithm sorts the items in the right order.

Answer (score 4):

Independently of the question of mixing top and bottom guesses, an implicit drawback of the experimental process, as described, is that **the data related to the user's choice can only be exploited in the context of one particular version of the algorithm**:
When / if the algorithm or its parameters are ever slightly tuned, the record of past user's choices cannot be reused to validate the changes to the algorithm.

On mixing high and low results:
The main drawback of producing sets of items by mixing the algorithm's top and bottom guesses is that it may further **complicate the choice of the error/distance function used** to measure how well the algorithm performed.  Unless the two subsets of items (topmost choices, bottom most choices) are kept separately for the purpose of computing *distinct* measurements, typical statistical measures of the error (say RMSE) will not be a good measurement of the effective algorithm's quality.
For example, an algorithm which frequently suggests, low guesses items which end up being picked as top choices by the user may have the same averaged error rate than an algorithm which never confuses highs with lows, but where there the user tends to reorders the items more within their subset.

A second drawback is that the algorithm evaluation method may merely qualify its ability of filtering the *relative* like/dislike of users *for items it [the algorithm] chooses* **rather than its ability of producing the user's *actual* top choices.**
In other words the user's actual top choices may never be offered to him; so yeah the algorithm does a good job at guessing that user will like say Rock-and-Roll before Rap, but never guessing that in fact user prefers Classical Baroque music over all.

Comment: I'm currently measuring the accuracy between the user's relative ordering of the 10 items he sees and the order the algorithm gave it, and if the algorithm actually chose the top 5 the user did.

Comment: But again, do you have a better idea of how to show that the algorithm chose good items ? I mean, I can't let the user order the entire database and check ....